# Getting Puppeteer to wait for a given class to appear/render on a page?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to load a page, and then wait for the text (or class in this case) to be rendered before I get the content.

This example works.

```
async function test() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page    = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://sunnythailand.com');

    // Wait until the page is fully rendered
    while (content.indexOf("scrapebot_description") < 0) {
        console.log("looking for scrapebot_description")    
        await new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(()=> resolve() ,1000));
        content = await page.content();
    }
    console.log("scrapebot_description FOUND!!!")   

    await browser.close();
}
```

My question is, can I do this easier with puppeteer?

I tried this:

```
    await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("scrapebot_description")');
```

But that just hangs there forever, nothing ever happens...
(to be honest I dont understand what querySelector is, so perhaps the problem is there)

I also tried this:

```
    var checkText = "scrapebot_description"
    await page.evaluate((checkText) => {
        console.log("scrapebot_description FOUND IT!!");
    },{checkText});
```

This also does not work.

This is the last element to render on the page what im waiting for....

```
    <span class="hide scrapebot_description ng-binding" ng-bind="'transFrontDescription' | translate">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
async function test() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page    = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://sunnythailand.com');

  const selector = '.scrapebot_description' // or #scrapebot_description
  await page.waitForSelector(selector)

  console.log("scrapebot_description FOUND!!!")   

  await browser.close();
}
```